# Show that (A + B) + C = A + (B + C)

Tags: vector-spaces

> For any subsets $A$ and $B$ of vector space $V$ we define the set sum $A + B$ by $A + B = \{\alpha + \beta : \alpha \in A, \beta \in B\}$. Show that $(A+B)+C = A+(B+C)$.

Given the question, since C is not defined, is it appropriate to assume that $\gamma \in C$ is added to the set sum $A + B$?

Then I could show that $$(A+B)+C = (\alpha + \beta) + \gamma = \alpha + (\beta + \gamma) = A + (B + C)$$

Is this complete enough?

edit: adding in set equality proof:

---

Suppose $x \in (A + B) + C$. Then $x \in (A+B)$ or $x\in C$. If $x\in (A+B)$, $x\in A$ or $x \in B$. Thus $(A + B) + C \subset A + (B + C)$.

Suppose $x \in A + (B+C)$. Then $x \in A$ or $x \in (B+C)$. If $x \in (B+C)$, $x\in B$ or $x \in C$. Thus $A + (B+C) \subset (A+B)+C$.

Comment: In your first equality you have a set which is equal to an element of that set, so it does not make sense. Have you learned how to show two sets are equal?

Comment: oh yes I have. So then I just show that the set $(A + B) + C$ is equal to the set $A + (B + C)$ then? I would show that they are equal by showing that each is a subset of the other

Comment: Exactly. Take an element from one and show it is an element of the other and vice versa.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip I am confident in the main idea, but might be lacking a detail or two. Would you mind looking it over really quick?

Comment: You're heading in the right direction, but when you say $x\in A+(B+C)$, that means there is some $\alpha\in A$ and $\mu\in B+C$ so that $x=\alpha+\mu$.

Comment: hmm that makes sense. The only set equality proofs I did were with unions/intersections of sets so I thought that $(A + (B+C)$ could be treated as $(A \cup (B\cup C)$. I am not sure what to do with the information you gave me

Comment: Bear in mind that $A$ $B$ and $C$ are just place holder names.  $[X] + [Y] = \{\mu + \nu| \mu \in [X], \nu \in [Y]$ so that would simply meas $(A+B) + C = \{\lambda + \gamma| \lambda \in A+B, \gamma \in C\}$.  You have to prove that that is equal to $A + (B+C) = \{\alpha + \omicron| \alpha \in A, \omicron \in B+C\}$. Can you do that?  My advice prove one is a subset of the other and vice versa.

Comment: $(A+B)+C = (\alpha + \beta) + \gamma = \alpha + (\beta + \gamma) = A + (B + C)$.  I don't want to be discouraging or nitpicky but that doesn't make sense.  $(A+B) + C$ is a vector space.  $(\alpha + \beta) + \gamma$ is the sum of three vectors that have not actually been introduced yet.  The sum of three vectors is a vector and a vector is not a vector space so $(A+B) +C= (\alpha + \beta) + \gamma$ is meaningless.

Comment: "Suppose x∈A+(B+C). Then x∈A or x∈(B+C)."   Let $A= \{1,2,3\}, B=\{101,102,103\}$ and $C=\{1001, 1002, 1003\}$ then $102+1003 = 1105\in B+C$ and $2+1105 = 1107\in A+(B+C)$.  But $1107\not \in A$.  And $1107 \not \in B+C$.

Comment: You have to say that if $x \in A + (B+C)$ then there is an $a \in A$ and a $k \in B+C$ so that $x = a + k$.  As $k \in B+C$ there is a $b \in B$ and $c \in C$  so that $k = b+c$.  So $x = a +k = a + b + c$.  But $a + b \in A+B$ and $c \in C$ so $x = a+b + c \in (A+B) + C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, you need to show that $A+(B+C)\subset (A+B)+C$ and vice versa. I will show one direction and leave the reverse direction to you.

Let $x\in A+(B+C)$. Then by definition of addition of sets, there is some $\alpha\in A$ and some $\mu\in B+C$ so that $x=\alpha+\mu$. But now, since $\mu \in B+C$, that means that there is some $\beta\in B$ and some $\gamma\in C$ such that $\mu=\beta+\gamma$. So $x=\alpha+(\beta+\gamma)$. By associativity of addition in $V$, this is the same as $(\alpha+\beta)+\gamma$. Now $\alpha+\beta\in A+B$ and $\gamma\in C$, which implies that $x=(\alpha+\beta)+\gamma\in (A+B)+C$, as desired.